# Alternative to i18n_routing gem that works with Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-4

After updating my Rails site to version 4 I got some serious problems with the i18n_routing gem - https://github.com/kwi/i18n_routing/issues/43 - it works fine with resource routes thanks to fixes in a fork, but named routes wont work.

So, the question is: does anyone know of a solid alternative to this gem that works with Rails 4?

Thanks!